# Selecting active row and first row in VBA Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

How can I select the row associated with the current active cell AND the first row?

I have:

```
    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
    Range("1:1").Select
```

But when the second "Select" is run, it removes the first select, so I end with just the first row. How to I get both selected at once?

Thank you!

Comment: Ideally you do not `Select` anything in your code. 99% of the time this is unnecessary, as the `Selection` returns a `Range` object, it is better practice to simply use a `Range` variable, or refer to the range explicitly.  One exception would be where the selection might be part of a user interface or the end of the macro, but ordinarily, it's never needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Union(ActiveCell.EntireRow, Cells(1, 1).EntireRow).Select
```